# How to convert PDF to PPT or ODP?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I need to convert a PDF file to PPT file. Are there any programs which can do that?

I don't need anything fancy. I just need to have contents of each page turned from PDF to PPT. No hyperlinks, no animations or anything similar.

Comment: Similar question on different sites: ■ [ms office - Converting PDF to Powerpoint, importing each slide as a singular picture - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/366417) ■ [libreoffice - Is there any tool to convert pdf to ppt/odp slides in Linux/ Ubuntu offline? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/797836) ■ [microsoft powerpoint - How to convert PDF to PPT or ODP? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/268244) ■ [conversion - Export beamer slides to powerpoint/openoffice-impress/keynote editable format - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21986)

Comment: Tools are evolving and now *LibreOffice* can directly imports PDF, see details and other solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633247/262081) (last link of @user202729's comment).

Answer (score 4):

The desired result can also be achieved without proprietary tools. If you have GhostScript installed, you can convert your PDF presentation into a set of JPG images using:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -sOutputFile='page-%00d.jpg' YOURFILE.pdf
```

Then, with the [plugin](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/photo-album-gui) for OpenOffice/LibreOffice create a presentation where each image fills exactly one slide. You can also easily keep the order of the pages by choosing the plugin option "natural sorting".

I have written [an article on the topic in my blog](http://www.dominic-scheurer.de/allgemein/38/pdf2odp), unfortunately in German only.

Comment: use -sDEVICE=png16m for text without jpeg artifacts; use LibreOffice's Insert>Image>Photo Album to insert them all.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of utilities and helps available on the web to do this, including:

- [PDFPowerPoint](http://www.convertpdftopowerpoint.com/)
- [EHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_5013505_convert-pdf-powerpoint.html)
- [PPTools](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00054.htm)
- [imToo](http://www.imtoo.com/pdf-to-powerpoint-converter.html)

You can also take the very cheap, manual route of manually copy/paste each page of the PDF file to a slide in Powerpoint.

Comment: PDFPowerpoint works perfectly. Don't need login or any data hog